# Delphi Indy TCP Server Remote Client-IP

Tags: delphi, server, tcp, indy

When a client connects to my TCP server, i can identify him via:

> AContext.Binding.PeerIP

This works for clients in a local network, and also for remote clients.
But on some sites there are 2 routers.
So the TCP-port has to be forwarded in both router.
This means that all clients that are connecting remotely are identified as '192.168.1.1' instead of with their own IP address.

When i am doing the same with a DataSnap server, i can use:

> IpAddress := Session.GetData('RemoteIP');

This gives back the 'real' clients IP, event through both routers.

So, is there a way to do the same with an Indy TCP-server?

Comment: DataSnap works over HTTP. When an HTTP connection passes through routers/proxies, extra HTTP headers may be added to identify the remote party that is being forwarded. There is no such feature in TCP itself. So the only way for your server to identify the clients uniquely is if the clients identify themselves to your server, such as via authentication.

Comment: Ah. Ok, makes sense. Thanks.